# Spring Batch multiresourceitemwriter with fileName in footer

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am using multiresourceitemwriter and able to generate multiple files with the difference index, passing flatfileitemwriter as deligate but I want add file name and count of the record into the footer.

Not sure how to do that.please suggest a way.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example? Please, see: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.